# Find two cells and use them as the range for formatting

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I created VBA coder to determine a dynamic range for formatting. I want to define two cells in a row and apply formatting to the range.

```vb
Sub RANGEFORMAT()
'
' RANGEFORMAT Macro
'

'
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(3).Find(What:="Total", LookAt:=xlWhole)
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(3).Find(What:="100 - Indirect Labour - Shop", LookAt:=xlWhole)
Range(rng2:rng).Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 90
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
End Sub
```

The line `Range(rng2:rng).Select` is incorrect.

What is the syntax to define the ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to `Select`. Also, it is preferable to test if both `Find` calls succeeded, before applying formatting.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Rows(3).Find(What:="Total", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = .Rows(3).Find(What:="100 - Indirect Labour - Shop", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    ' Check to see if the Find succeeded
    If Not rng Is Nothing And Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
         ApplyTheFormat .Range(rng2, rng)
    End If
End With

....

Private Sub ApplyTheFormat(ByVal rng As Range)
   With rng
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 90
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The check portion gives a syntax error. I'm glad I was sort of in the ballpark for defining the range though and now understand better the passthrough of the ranges to the actual formatting step.  Thanks Ben!

Comment: @AdamArdea - oops forgot a `Then`, added.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen that fixed the error however I am getting another error saying an ```End Sub``` should go after the first ```End With``` following the ```Find``` check but there is a private sub syntax following so I don't understand why.

Comment: `Private Sub ApplyTheFormat` is a separate subroutine. It sounds like you have it nested inside the primary subroutine the `Find` is in, but it really should be afterwards.

Comment: Yep now it works almost perfectly. I just need to offset the ```Find``` "Total" range by 1 and its perfect which I think I can do. Thanks again @BigBen